# What is the Windows Phone Runtime?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've always understood "runtime" to mean the point at when an application is running. But, watching the videos from Microsoft Academy they referrer to "Windows Phone Runtime and API's".

Is it called the Windows Phone Runtime because you applications interact with the Windows Phone OS - which is obviously running, hence "Runtime"? Or have I missed the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone Runtime is an API, like .NET for Windows Phone. Take a look at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626516(v=vs.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207212(v=vs.105).aspx